# ffmpeg stich multiple videos

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have multiple videos of same resolution. Each video has a different length. And I also have a fixed length for output file. Let's say 4 minutes. Let's assume there are 4 input files each of 30 seconds but each input file could have different length. I want to put first 30 secs of output file blank and the next 30 secs as 1st input file and next 10 secs as blank and next 30 secs as 2nd input file so on. Basically I have a predetermined start point for each input file and between the gaps there should be black screen. How can I achieve this ? ffmpeg commands are fine but I'm going to have to automate this in nodejs so if you can give me any tips on it that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single ffmpeg command to do this so I had to split the problem into a smaller problems.

First I generated a list of video segments that are going to a part of the final output video. Now some of these segments are already present and some are to be a black video.
So I used an ffmpeg command to generate a black video with silent audio with the desired length. So now I have all the segments I need and it's just a matter of combining them one after another.